# Share Data Between Visual Web Parts on different pages

Tags: c#, sharepoint, session

I have a need to share information from Web Parts on one page, with Web Parts on a second page. SharePoint does not have a default Session State, and let's say for arguments sake I cannot enable Session.

If there is a LOT of information, more than can be sent via Query String, is there another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the data that needs to be passed along, there are different ways to go about it. My first idea would probably be to save it in cookies on the active user. Another alternative is to save data to the property bag of the SPUser-object of the current user.
Really feels like a scenario to user Session-state though.. :)